# Apache Camel Kafka "consumerCount" issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

I am using apache camel version 3.11.1, In which I am using apache camel Kafka for asynchronous communication.
There is a property named "consumersCount". Its value has been set to 3.
So my application has 8 instances, So the total consumers are set to 24.

The issue is when any issue with the database e.g. DB goes down, We have set up a resilience process in Camel that disconnects the kafka and the app stops receiving the messages. It checks the health of the DB, if it's fine then it tries to establish the connection to Kafka but the count of the consumers never goes to 24. It is random sometimes we notice it as 15 or 12 or 8.

Is there anything we can do to get this issue resolved or anything I am missing here?

I have tried upgrading the camel version but have run into multiple issues.